# Merdles asks for a knife with a darker handle

Tags: plot-explanation, little-dorrit

In the second to last episode of Little Dorrit, in one of the last scenes, Merdles asks for a penknife. When Sparkler hands him the knife he asks if he could have one with a "darker" handle.
Shortly after, we see the scene where he has killed himself in the bathtub. Most probably with the penknife.

My question is: why did he ask for one with a *darker* handle? I have never read the book so if someone has, and that gives more context, or if it is only in the movie, let me know.

Comment: It's in the book: https://victorianweb.org/art/illustration/phiz/196.html I presume he knows his suicide will ruin the knife, especially if it is one with a white handle. Perhaps ask @ https://literature.stackexchange.com/ if there is any deeper meaning. Google didn't reveal anything.

Comment: This question has been [reasked and answered](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18509/17) on Literature SE.